# Convert DataURL image to image file in java

Tags: javascript, java, html, image, servlets

I am receiving image DataURL in my java servlet it looks like:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA...
```

I need to save it as an image file, how can I do that?

Comment: Often having a bit of code you've actually tried will provide better responses. You probably need to decode this and save this as you would any other file. Hopefully that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way<sup>1</sup> to do it is as follows:

```
String str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA...";
byte[] imagedata = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str.substring(str.indexOf(",") + 1));
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imagedata));
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("img.png"));
```

---

*Notes*

1. In order to use the class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`, you need Java 6 o greater.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `str.substring(str.indexOf(",") + 1)`?  And if the image's MIME type is `image/jpeg`, you probably don't want to write it as a PNG.

Comment: ① *Yup*. `+ 1`. Thanks! ;) ② Humm... I don't know. May be *I* want to write to PNG format... but the OP... I don't know. :P

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have do this, but I have got some errors, an exception after
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imagedata));

Comment: What is the exception? You can use http://pastie.org/ for shared the output/code. :)

Comment: As of Java 8 you should use `byte[] imagedata = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.substring(str.indexOf(",") + 1));` instead of DatatypeConverter