# How to Capture Image using Web Camera in JSP only (Without using Servlet) and save it into MS SQL Server

Tags: java, jsp

I want  to capture the image using web camera and store it into MS SQL Server database.

I am able to capture the image using web camera but right now i am trying to pass the image to next page but could not get the image on next jsp to process the image.

Code to capture image

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Web  camera - Testing</title>

    <script>

        // Put event listeners into place
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                    video = document.getElementById("video"),
                    videoObj = {"video": true},
            errBack = function (error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function () {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 213, 160);
                document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

//                    document.getElementById('video').style.display = "none";  // hide the live image video portin after click on take picture
            });



        }, false);

    </script>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>Capture Image using Camera!</h1>

    <!--
     Ideally these elements aren't created until it's confirmed that the 
     client supports video/camera, but for the sake of illustrating the 
     elements involved, they are created with markup (not JavaScript)
    -->
    <video id="video" width="213" height="160" autoplay></video>
    <button id="snap">Capture Photo</button>

    <form action="savetesting.jsp" method="post">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="213" height="160"  name="ImageFile1" style="display: none;"></canvas>

        <img id="canvasImg" name="ImageFile"><img>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

but now i am trying to get the captured image using

```
request.getParameter("ImageFile");
```

but could not succeed.

Please help me out with this issue, How to get the image on next page then i will try to save the image in MS SQL Server Database but only using JSP (without using Servlet).

Comment: name="ImageFile1" in the form but you getting request.getParameter("ImageFile"); both needs to be uniform!

Comment: i have tried to get the image source using both ImageFile and ImageFile1 but could not get the image source

Comment: When I use your above code in a file, it opens a blank page. not the webcam ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `canvas` nor `img` are form input fields, even when placed inside `form` tag. Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />
```

to your form, and

```
document.getElementById('ImageData').value = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

to the `click` event handler of the `snap` button.

Then, in JSP, get the image data (in the [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) format) using

```
String imageData = request.getParameter("ImageData");
```

and process them using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` as described in [Convert DataURL image to image file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424280/convert-dataurl-image-to-image-file-in-java)

Comment: yes the above code works to get the image source on next page using hidden field.

Thank you for the help.

Now i m converting the base64 data to byte Array to save the image into Database.

Comment: @KaranChopra Would you mind to accept my answer then?

Comment: now what i want to save the image on web server and then save the image as byte into MS SQL Server Database;

Comment: @KaranChopra See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application for how to save it (it talks about servlets, but it will be the same in JSP), and then http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/69-jdbc/203-how-to-storeretrieve-image-tofrom-sqlserver.html for storing it into MS SQL.

Comment: Btw. I wonder, why you cannot use servlet - it's definitely considered an anti-pattern to have such logic in JSP, as JSPs should be the View part (or a template), not the business logic part.

Comment: actually i have to just integrate that feature in already running project so that's why and the project is made only with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, AJAX and JSP.